# Iterating over a String in java & webdriver

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, for-loop

I'm including Webdriver in the Q just in case but suspect it's a simple Java syntax issue.  I'm creating a new article in a CMS system in one class then passing the article URL into a variable newArticlePath.

I'm then using a new class (below) to append the path onto a base URL so the tests can resolve the complete URL to run tests against.  The reason I need an array or list is because I will be creating up to 6 unique paths in a suite of tests before passing to this class and running tests in a for loop, on each URL respectively.

What I want is the optimal solution for this - what I am getting is a nullpointerexception.  I realise I only have 1 item in my array, for debugging purposes:

```
public class ArticleWebsiteDisplayTest {
private static WebDriver driver;
public static String baseURL = "http://test-env.local/";
public static String newArticlePath = ArticleCreator.getnewArticlePath();
public String[] articlesArray = {newArticlePath};

public static void setup() {

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}

@Test
public void checkSocialMediaButtons() {
    for (String s : articlesArray) {

        driver.get(baseURL + s); //this is where the IDE points to the exception

        //some assertions here
```

I realise this is a beginners Q - thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please explain your question a bit more? In particular, what is "this" in "optimal solution for this"?

Comment: Read the error message and stack trace of the exception. It tells you what and where the problem is. Ignoring error message is the best way to lose hours searching at the wrong place. driver is null, because it's not initialized. The test method doesn't initialize it, and it's not initialized in any method annotated with `@Before` or `@BeforeClass`.

Comment: Thank you - I had forgotten the annotation @BeforeClass